# How to avoid code duplication issue in this case?

Tags: c++

I have 2 similar functions, that are doing some calculations with graph nodes or edges.

```
void foo(const VertexMgr& mgr, const std::string name)
{
    // Skipped..
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; ++i)
    {
        // Skipped
        const A& a = CreateSomething();
        for (IterType<Vertex> it = a->vertices(); it != NULL(); ++it)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

void goo(const EdgeMgr& mgr, const std::string& name)
{
    // Skipped..
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; ++i)
    {
        // Skipped
        const A& a = CreateSomething();
        for (IterType<Edge> it = a->edges(); it != NULL(); ++it)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

The question is: How to get rid of the code duplication in this situation.
Are there possible solution with templates?

Comment: Are the `VertexMgr` and `EdgeMgr` classes related?  You could use the parent class as the method parameter.  This is called polymorphism by the way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, edges and vertices are fundamentally different concepts IMO, so I don't really see the polymorphism here, apart from both objects having some iterable childs, which is true for many other unrelated objects as well.

Comment: Please, post a complete example, one that at least compiles.

Comment: You could make the manager be a template parameter, and give it a member typedef that gets Vertex or Edge out

Comment: The main question is IMO, is the "do something" part really the same, which would show the common traits. Otherwise the only "benefit" of the template would be to safe the duplication of the loop.

Comment: The part that is being repeated in both or more functions, can be a function of its own... right? ie. Do other stuff and then call that `common-function(type,..other args)`,  then do function specific stuff again.

Comment: @M.M, IterType is a polymorph iterator type, and NULL() returns object of an empty class.

Comment: `NULL` is a macro defined as `0` , not an empty class

Comment: @M,M, actually I have something like this: class Null{}; inline Null NULL() { return Null(); } :)

Comment: @NarekAt Wow. Making it impossible to include standard library headers, or overriding the names provided by the standard library headers, is pretty much horrible for maintenance. If you're the only one who has to maintain this code and you're fine with it, then okay, but if there's even a chance that someone else will have to end up maintaining it, just write `Null()` directly, getting rid of your inline function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a template argument for the `Vertex`/`Edge` and manager object, and then [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) for the function to call.

Wrap the actual function call to make the calling easier. Maybe something like

```
template<typename MgrT, typename ItrT, typename FunT>
void foo(const MgrT& mgr, const std::string& name, FunT& fn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // Skipped
        const A& a = CreateSomething();
        for (IterType<ItrT> it = fn(a); it != NULL(); ++it)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}

void foo(const EdgeMgr& mgr, const std::string& name)
{
    foo<EdgeMgr, Edge>(mgr, name, std::mem_fn(&A::edges));
}

void foo(const VerticeMgr& mgr, const std::string& name)
{
    foo<VertexMgr, Vertex>(mgr, name, std::mem_fn(&A::vertices));
}
```

<sub>Not tested but it should hopefully provide a starting point.</sub>

Comment: Cool, that's really helpful. Thank You :)

Comment: Why is `foo` even bothering with managers? `template<typename GraphElements, typename ItrT>
void foo(GraphElements const& elems, const std::string& name)`, call as `foo(mgr.edges(), name)`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to method pointer, you may do

```
template <typename T> IterType<T> GetIterType(A&);

template <> IterType<Vertex> GetIterType<Vertex>(A& a) { return a->vertices(); }
template <> IterType<Edge> GetIterType<Edge>(A& a) { return a->edges(); }

template <typeame Mgr>
void foo(const Mgr& mgr, const std::string name)
{
    using itr_type = typename Mgr::itr_type; // That assumes that you add using in Mgr
    //else you have to create an external traits.

    // Skipped..
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // Skipped
        const A& a = CreateSomething();
        for (IterType<itr_type> it = GetIterType<itr_type>(a); it != NULL(); ++it)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

An other alternative would be to use `auto it` instead of `IterType<..> it` and rename (or *alias*) `vertices()`/`edges()` by a common name (`data()`).

Comment: Or change the `GetIterType<Vertex>` specialisation to `GetIterType<VertexMgr>` (and similarly for `Edge`), and call `GetIterType<Mgr>(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to templetize the function:

```
template<class Manager>
void foo(const Manager& mgr, const std::string& name)
{
    // Skipped..
    for (int i = 0; i< 100; ++i)
    {
        // Skipped
        const A& a = CreateSomething();
        for (auto it = Manager::get_iterator(a); it != NULL(); ++it)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how to ilmplement `get_iterator`:

```
struct EdgeMgr {
    static IterType<Edge> get_iterator(A& a) {
        return a.edges();
    }
};
struct VertexMgr {
    static IterType<Vertex> get_iterator(A& a) {
        return a.vertices();
    }
};
```

To further make `get_iterator` useful with any type, you can use a template:

```
struct EdgeMgr {
    template<class T>
    static IterType<Edge> get_iterator(T& a) {
        return a.edges();
    }
};
// ....
Manager::template get_iterator<A>(a)
```